# Parallel for each loop does not save all files

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I writing on an image converter. When I use parallel for each not all images are saved. Is the processing too fast for writing files on disk?

Here is my code:

```
private void convert()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(source.GetFiles("*.tif"), 
         new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, 
         file =>
         {                  
            fileName = file.Name;
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceFolderPath + "\\" + file);
            image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.XYZ;
            image.GammaCorrect(2.4);
            image.Write(destinationFolderPath + "\\" + fileName);
         });
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you see the same when you do a File.Copy from source to destination path instead of using MagickImage?

Comment: it wouldnt be that the processing is too fast, it could be a host of other things, a bit of debugging should help such as logging that filename tried to be processed.. and that it got to be written without error, etc.

Comment: Using File.Copy gives the Error that files allready exist in the destination Folder (but it is empty before running). So i think the loop takes files tiwce?

Answer (score 3):

Try disposing the `image`:

```
private void convert()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(source.GetFiles("*.tif"), 
         new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, 
         file =>
         {                  
            fileName = file.Name;
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceFolderPath + "\\" + file))
            {
                image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.XYZ;
                image.GammaCorrect(2.4);
                image.Write(destinationFolderPath + "\\" + fileName);
            }
         });
}
```

Comment: Seems the [`MagickImage` class](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET/Framework/MagickImage.cs#L42) does not implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: True. Found this [old docs](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20image) on CodePlex with `using`.

Comment: On the other hand, there _is_ a [`MagicImage` class](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET/Native/MagickImage.cs#L31) that _does_ implement `IDisposable`. I'm confused.

Comment: @UweKeim It's a partial class. So it _does_ implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Does it throw any exception? Try enclosing it in a `try..catch` block and set a breakpoint inside the `catch`.